# Why does gswin32.exe have a 237-character limit on the value of its sOutputFile parameter?

Tags: windows, ghostscript

I am using version 8.71 and my OS is Windows XP SP3.  The error I get is as follows:

```
Error: /undefinedfilename in --showpage--
Operand stack:
   1   true
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
-   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   fa
lse   1   %stopped_push   1878   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_
pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1
3   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
  1761   0   9   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1165/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75
/200(L)--   --dict:108/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:288/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)-
-   --dict:6/8(L)--   --dict:26/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Close this window with the close button on the title bar or the system menu.
```

The value of sOutputFile that I pass is something like 234 characters plus `%03d` so the file name effectively generated is 237 characters.

Comment: What is the length of the full path + OutputFile name?

Answer (score 1):

[subst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst) is your friend when requirments call for stupidly long paths

Answer (score 0):

I think because of OS/FS limitations. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-xp-and-vista/265782#265782) for numbers

Comment: You're right.  When I don't specify a placeholder (%03d), 255 characters in sOutputFile produces the same error.  What's weird though is that the limit if there's a placeholder is just 237 (including %03d).

Comment: The limit is on the path (full path), thats probably why you get 237

Comment: I don't understand.  When expanded, the effective file name should be no more than 240.