# C#: Maximum file name length for OLE file

Tags: c#, file, ole, maxlength

I used WinAPI function to create OLE file in C#. The WinAPI function is:

```
   [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    public static extern int OleCreateFromFile(
        [In] ref Guid rclsid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszFileName,
        [In] ref Guid riid, uint renderopt,
        [In] IntPtr pFormatEtc,
        IOleClientSite pClientSite,
        IStorage pStg,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppvObj);
```

I used this function in C# application as below:

```
     hResult = OleAPI.OleCreateFromFile(ref clsid,
                                            sourceFileFullPath,
                                            ref IID_IOleObject,
                                            (uint)OLERENDER.OLERENDER_DRAW,
                                            IntPtr.Zero,
                                            pOleClientSite,
                                            pStorage,
                                            out pOleObjectOut);
```

The function works perfectly.
But when the length of filename of the file is 140, it failed to create OLE file. The return value of hResult is -2147467259.

The value of 
       sourceFileFullPath="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TmpTzStore1\pju3wswj.jmq\000008F6\CalendarRepeddsfsfdsfsfat344Issue5sdfdfsfsfdsfdsfsdsdfdsfsf00kbCalendarRepeatIssue500kbCalendarRepeatIssue500kbCalendarRepeatIssue500kb.xlsx"

The length of filename                         (CalendarRepeddsfsfdsfsfat344Issue5sdfdfsfsfdsfdsfsdsdfdsfsf00kbCalendarRepeatIssue500kbCalendarRepeatIssue500kbCalendarRepeatIssue500kb.xlsx) is 140.

But when I trimmed the file name to 120, it worked.

I wanted to know if there is any limitation in the filename length for OLE file. 
Since I tried it for different application files( doc,docx,txt,pdf...). The results varied for different files.

I don't know what is the exact the file name length that this API supports. Or it is dependent on the OS? I am using Windows Server 2008.

Thanks
Prakash

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-xp-and-vista

Answer (score 0):

The maximum file name length of the **complete** filename length, including the path, is ([about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-xp-and-vista)) 259 characters. The length of the path you pasted is 216 characters, so this should be under the limit.

That the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690116(VS.85).aspx) [pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693715(v=VS.85).aspx) do not describe a specific maximum length implies that 259 characters should be the maximum.

I could not find any documentation on this discrepancy. Maybe one or more of your paths are softlinks to path names that are in reality longer.

Comment: Amazing thing happened. When I used the file name which have only alphabetic characters but having the length 140, it worked.

Comment: You're kidding! You mean only A through Z?

Comment: Yes. I used only A, B and C. Its file name is ABCABCABCABCABABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC.xlsx

Comment: The variable thing is path. Its is temp folder generated from the code. For example, C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\TmpTzStore0\\jhqqln14.v2o\\000008F6\. In this path, the only variable is "jhqqln14.v2o".