# resource files corrupt after switching laptops

Tags: c#, winforms, svn

Error   1   Cannot write to the output file "C:\Users\Daan\Desktop\zeebregts_soft\C#\zeebregtsCs\zeebregtsCs\obj\x86\Debug\zeebregtsCs.Properties.Resources.resources". Parameter is not valid. zeebregtsCs

Keep getting this error. I'm using ankhsvn + assembla. installed vs2010 pro on new laptop and connected to repository.

I've tried deleting resource(file)s and adding them, error keeps returning. Anyone got any insight?

Comment: Are they both using the same OS, visual studio version, SVN version etc? None *should* be excuses, but I'm trying to limit the variables...

Comment: at 120+ characters the path is long, but not [near the limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-xp-and-vista)

Comment: Windows version is different old: ms windows server 2003 r2 (x86??) new:win 7 home prem x64. I didn't think about that. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: I think could be permission issue with your folders, also did you try a clean build ?

Comment: jup, if you mean buil>clean. What should my permissions be? I'm listed as owner and full control set as permissions..

Comment: Thnx to Marc Gravell I could narrow my search. He gave me the idea that it might be os based problem. 
I found out that .tiff files don't work in vs + win 7. So changed all images to .bmp and presto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc put me on the right track. After googleling some more I found that .tiff files (used for my btns) don't like Win7. So converted them all to bmp and presto. everything's back to normal!