# Symfony 2.1-x / Composer ErrorException with DoctrineBundle

Tags: doctrine, symfony-2.1, composer-php

*** Update: the issue could be resolved by reducing the Directory depth ***

I've tried to install the latest Symfony version (2.1.6, 2.1.5, 2.1.x-dev) via the recommended way using composer but it always fails with the same error:

> C:\Users\made\eclipse-workspace\template-compiler\template-compiler\lib\server\symfony\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\b05c336283dc24eb535a50f89ce9d91c.0 - Das Handle ist ung¬tig.

Searching gave me no further clues until now and i would like to avoid having to create everything from scratch. I tried the self-udpate feature of composer and all of the mentioned versions above but the installation still fails. I'm using the git Bash on Win7 with PHP 5.3.8 but I also tried PHP 5.4.10

Complete Output:

```
C:\Users\made\eclipse-workspace\template-compiler\template-compiler\lib\server>C:\Users\made\AppData\Roaming\Composer\bin\composer
 create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition symfony 2.1.6
Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.1.6)
  - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.1.6)
    Loading from cache

Created project in symfony
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
  - Installing doctrine/common (2.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/dbal (2.3.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing twig/twig (v1.11.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.1.6)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.0.0)
    Downloading: 100%
C:\Users\made\eclipse-workspace\template-compiler\template-compiler\lib\server\symfony\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Doctrine\Bu
ndle\DoctrineBundle\5338efeb67b3e71765a5179fbadb1633.0 - Das Handle ist ungültig.



  [ErrorException]
  ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\Users\made\eclipse-workspace\template-compiler\template-compiler\lib\server\symfony\vendor/doctrine/
  doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/DoctrineBundle-1.0.0\Tests\DependencyInjection\Fixtures\Bundles\Vendor\Annotat
  ionsBundle/AnnotationsBundle.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-custom-installers]
[--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] package [directory] [version]



C:\Users\made\eclipse-workspace\template-compiler\template-compiler\lib\server>
```

Comment: Could you paste the complete output?

Comment: That's odd, but true: reducing the depth of installation directory helped me with the same exact problem.

Comment: I've made some digging, and found out that this was due to limitation to path + file name in Windows.
Find more here: [Maximum filename length in NTFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue could be resolved by reducing the Directory depth

PS: now i have the rep score to solve this...