# How much is the filename size limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, io

I want to rename image files uploaded to my website and give them a bit of description. I'm using ASP.NET, C# and of course Windows hosting. the file names will contain Unicode characters. how much is the filename size limit in these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Individual components of a filename (i.e. each subdirectory along the
>   path, and the final filename) are limited to 255 characters, and the
>   total path length is limited to approximately 32,000 characters.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista)

[MSDN more reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx)

However, the issue will be more due to the browser as the full URL is limited to a number of characters and it's different per browser. Some posts here suggest you should [limited to 2000 characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers/417184#417184)

To read more about browser limits, I [suggest you read here](http://wiert.me/2010/04/20/maximum-url-lengths/) but please note for future proofing, **the comments I've made here and posts I've cited will become outdated. You need to do your own research at the time of reading this!**