# Python's os.walk() fails in Windows when there are long filenames

Tags: python, windows, file, filenames, os.walk

I use python os.walk() to get files and dirs in some directories, but there're files whose names are too long(>300), os.walk() return nothing, use onerror I get '[Error 234] More data is available'. I tried to use yield, but also get nothing and shows 'Traceback: StopIteration'.

OS is windows, code is simple. I have tested with a directory, if there's long-name file, problem occur, while if rename the long-name files with short names, code can get correct result.

I can do nothing for these directories, such as rename or move the long-name files. 
Please help me to solve the problem!

```
def t(a):
  for root,dirs,files in os.walk(a): 
    print root,dirs,files
t('c:/test/1')
```

Comment: I wonder what operating system lets you have name files that long.

Comment: Can you provide us with some more details?  What os are you using, and can you show us a minimal version of your code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: windows, code simple, no any special: for root,dirs,files in os.walk(...): print root . I have tested, if rename the long-name files with short names, code can get correct result.

Comment: I'm just reiterating what @larsks said, we need to see a minimal version of your code to help diagnose your problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows file names (including path) can not be greater than 255 characters, so the error you're seeing comes from Windows, not from Python - because somehow you managed to create such big file names, but now you can't read them. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista) for more details.

Comment: When use os.walk(), how to ignore long-name files and get other files and dirs whose names not long?

Comment: I tried some file-search tools, they can't find long-name files but can find all other files in the same directory!

Comment: I have tried catch exception using try..except..., but useless

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think of is to map the the folder to the specific directory. This will make the path way shorter. e.g. z:\myfile.xlsx instead of c:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\myfile.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

The limitation for maximum length for a path is 256. Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, this limitation have been removed, but you have to opt-in to this new behavior. You can either do one of these:

1. Open registry, navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\`, and create a new key with the name `LongPathsEnabled`, type REG_DWORD and value 1.
   2
2. In PowerShell command `New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force`

Read more about how Windows naming files, paths and namespaces [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation).

Or you can run a virtual machine using an Unix OS.