# mkdir and is_dir length limit?

Tags: php, mkdir

I created a folder through Windows Explorer, but `is_dir` returns `FALSE`.

A path that fails:

```
ficheiros/dinamicos/multimedia/imagem/areas/galerias/actividades/professores/iii-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx-abcdefg/__fmhidden__681d75e470b4fd52f7d3b468b8ce7b5b/__fmhidden__b14a7b8059d9c055954c92674ce60032
```

This one doesn't fail:

```
ficheiros/dinamicos/multimedia/imagem/areas/galerias/actividades/professores/iii-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx-a/__fmhidden__681d75e470b4fd52f7d3b468b8ce7b5b/__fmhidden__b14a7b8059d9c055954c92674ce60032
```

My code used to work flawlessly for months. After debugging it, I found that the problem was with `mkdir`/`is_dir`. The strange part is that it only happens when the path length was bigger than 218 characters (247 as absolute).

Is there any limit to the path length for `is_dir` and `mkdir` (in Windows environments)?

Comment: The file name limit is completely up to the OS (Windows, Mac) etc.

Comment: Could you submit the file path you are using? Are you looking at a network drive or a local drive?

Comment: It's a local drive, I'll mask the path but keep the length...

Comment: @MarioCesar, In windows max length of folder path is  "247 characters + `<NULL>`". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15971467/632951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows the character limit of file paths is 260 (with some exceptions) so the PHP `mk_dir` and `is_dir` functions may not work as you expect.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath

Comment: thank you. That should be the issue. It isn't that problematic since it will only be deployed in unix systems