# How to set the workspace root directory on Jenkins nodes?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

By default, jobs on a Jenkins node will be stored in `[Remote FS root]\workspace\`.

Currently, `[Remote FS root]` is set to `D:\`, so my jobs are in `D:\workspace\`. Due to the [255-characters limit on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265782/1515819), I need my job directories to be directly at the root of the drive.

How to set the workspace root directory to `D:\`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have to specify the following argument on startup of the Jenkins master node:

```
-Dhudson.model.Slave.workspaceRoot=D:/
```

To do so, find the `jenkins.xml` configuration file in `$JENKINS_HOME` and complete the `<arguments></arguments>` section.

Comment: It's worth noting that the [documentation for Jenkins properties](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) states that this property specifies the "name of the folder within the slave root directory to contain workspaces". So, if we wanted to use `D:\jobs` instead of `D:\workspace` on slaves, this property just needs to be set to `jobs`. It seems that specifying an absolute path overrides the use of the slave root directory as well.

Answer (score 3):

> By default, jobs on a Jenkins slave will be stored in [Remote FS root]\workspace\

It seems that, at least on Windows, this is not actually true.

I'm running Jenkins 1.480.3, and my slaves are run via `jenkins-slave.exe`and `jenkins-slave.xml` on Windows nodes.

Neither the XML file nor the service parameters store any path information, and *the `workspace` directory is created at the location of the `jenkins-slave.exe`, which is the same as the setting under `http://server/jenkins/computer/node_name/configure` -> **`Remote FS root`** the help for which reads:

> A slave needs to have a directory dedicated to Jenkins. Specify the
>   absolute path of this work directory on the slave, such as
>   '/var/jenkins' or 'c:\jenkins'. This should be a path local to the
>   slave machine. (...)
>
> Slaves do not maintain important data (other than active workspaces of
>   projects last built on it), so you can possibly set the slave
>   workspace to a temporary directory. The only downside of doing this is
>   that you may lose the up-to-date workspace if the slave is turned off.

So it seems it is actually possible to set the `workspace`on the slave via the Jenkins FS root for the slaves.

Also related: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12667

Comment: Yes, it's possible with the Jenkins FS root and that's why it's made for. However, jobs are put into `[Remote FS root]\workspace` whereas I need them to be in `[Remote FS root]`, which means my job1 will be in `D:\job1` instead of `D:\workspace\job1`.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert - the linked Jenkins issues says the same. Guess itÄs a valid case to not want it under the FS root/workspace.

Comment: Indeed. The workaround I suggest is good for now even if I am still hoping that this feature will be added one day.