# How to make jenkins slave machine work in a particular workspace directory

Tags: jenkins

I had given remote root directory as C:\jenkins for my jeknins slave but my robot framework actually work in D:\automation and place results there and when i try to execute single build steps it actualluy works on C:\jenkins\workspace\Job_name can anyone tell me how to make jenkins slave work in this D:\automation , i had actually tried giviing

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780554/how-to-set-the-workspace-root-directory-on-jenkins-slaves

Comment: That [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23780554/598141) is very old (2014), as is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30223282/598141) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46588929/598141). While probably all still valid, they correspond to the Jenkins 1.x era and there are more options now in 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be configured individually on each node, overriding the default location.

**Node Level:**
Under Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | Manage Nodes ...
< pick your node > | Configure
Remote root directory **[`D:\path\of\choice`]**

**Job Level:**
You can also change the workspace of an individual job under
`General | Advanced ...`

[ **X** ] Use custom workspace
Directory **[`D:\path\of\choice`]**

**System Level:**
There is also the [Jenkins System Properties](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) override:
**hudson.model.Slave.workspaceRoot** [ `workspace` ]
name of the folder within the slave root directory to contain workspaces

---

And for completeness, even though it's a bad idea to run jobs on the master:

**Master Specific** system property:
**jenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir** [ `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}` ]
Allows to change the directory layout for the job workspaces on the master node.

See **jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir** for supported placeholders.

Answer (score -1):

Well as described by @Ian W, Node level configurations can help you define your custom location in the Slave(Node). Make sure your Jenkins slave user has permissions on the folder.