# Jenkins Specify Remote Root Directory which creates "workspace" folder in the folder structure which i dont want

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I tried searching on different sites but couldn't find answer. My Question is
In Jenkins Slave Node, In Remote root directory, I specified -C:\MyJenkinsRun\ and it is creating folder structure as C:\MyJenkinsRun\workspace\Myprojectname
Actually I dont want workspace named folder. I just want C:\MyJenkinsRun\Myprojectname. 
In My Master, it is Not creating workspace named folder. It is creating the way I want which is C:\MyJenkinsRun\Myprojectname. 
I did many different ways to specify Remote Root directory in slave but counldn't find answer.
By the way My Global Configure system, Workspace Root Directory is set up as C:\MyJenkinsRun/${ITEM_FULLNAME} and Build Record Root Directory is set up as ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the workspace root directory on Jenkins slaves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780554/how-to-set-the-workspace-root-directory-on-jenkins-slaves)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23780554/27401 . The accepted answer there ought to help you, I think.