# PHP functions failure passing long path as parameter

Tags: php, iis

i'm struggling around a problem with some php functions like stat(), file size(), move_uploaded_file() and fopen().

Running my code on PHP 5.3.28 on IIS6 (unfortunately) i'm receiving an error using the above mentioned functions when i pass the path "../../../../ceceditalia/userfiles_orig/files/doc/Area_Riservata/CISP/26.GOUSSELOT_New_environmental_friendly_hot_rolled_steel_suitable_for_two_sides_enamelling_intended_for_the_manufacturing_of_tanks_and_silos_FRANCIA.pdf"

I already double-checked the file permissions and the only way i found to make these functions work with this file was reducing the path length (196 chars).
I also moved the file to the same directory as the php file (to be able to work without the rest of the path) and run the script adding one char at a time to the filename.
It only worked until i reached 196 chars.

After all my research i didn't find any php related limit about file paths and the Windows default MAX_PATH is 260 not 196.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista