# Puppet-Librarian, windows and Error: No such file or directory

Tags: puppet, librarian-puppet

On windows 2012 server edition, when I run puppet-librarian install I get the error below.

```
Error: No such file or directory - C:/Users/Administrator/infrastructure/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/opentable-windowsfeature/999.999.999/cache/tmp-unpacker20150907-1308-19kvk70/opentable-windowsfeature- 999.999.999/spec/acceptance/nodesets/windows-2008R2-serverstandard-x64.yml Error: Try 'puppet help module install' for usage
```

I think this is a generic windows problem and it took me a while to figure out the error.  Windows has a 255 char maximum length for the absolute file name.  Puppet-librarian doesn't give a good error message to indicate this is the root cause.  [Maximum filename length in NTFS (Windows XP and Windows Vista)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista).

Comment: librarian-puppet doesn't work well with the space in path. not windows friendly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Those spaces were introduced when I copied the error message from the shell; the actual file path doesn't have them.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with long file paths is likely due to puppet-librarian using PMT (Puppet Module Tool) to install the module. It's compounded by the fact that Librarian starts with this path `C:/Users/Administrator/infrastructure/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/opentable-windowsfeature/999.999.999/`, which is already long, and then PMT adds `cache/tmp-unpacker20150907-1308-19kvk70/opentable-windowsfeature-999.999.999` to the path, which exasperates the length even more.

PMT has issues with long paths. We'll be fixing that by adding LFN (Long File Name) support to it in a future release. Vote and watch [PUP-4866](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-4866) to know when this is fixed.

It appears that puppet-librarian will also need to be fixed due to the [following call](https://github.com/rodjek/librarian-puppet/blob/cdfffce57aed1a1a1ab15762f1e14c93dbc4034b/lib/librarian/puppet/source/forge/repo.rb#L111):

```
command.push(*[path.to_s, "--module_repository", module_repository, "--modulepath", path.to_s, "--module_working_dir", path.to_s, "--ignore-dependencies", target])
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to move the root directory from "C:/Users/Administrator/infrastructure" to "C:/infrastructure".