# Unable to Build the C# code through command line

Tags: c#, build, devenv

while building the the c# code from command line using **devenv**, I'm getting  this error: -
**The operation could not be completed. The filename or extension is too long. 
The system can not find the file specified**

The batch file command which i have used is :

```
devenv /build Release  E:\MES_TEST_tool\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MT20160404/trunk/POC/C#WorkSpace/LicenseManagementSystem/LicenseManagementSystem.sln >E:\MES_TEST_tool\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MEST_SCA_TestTool/logs/buildLogs.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a maximum length of characters per filename:

[Maximum filename length in NTFS (Windows XP and Windows Vista)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista)

Try moving your project/code and renaming it according

Comment: Moving the complete project/code is not that easy as many changes will be needed.
Is there any other possible way to build the code...
I tried with "\\?\" before the path ...
But not working for me..