# Tired of reinstalling Bitnami WAMP Stack 7.0 over and over again. Cannot install stack in a deeper directory

Tags: wamp, wampserver, bitnami

This is really REALLY damn frustrating. For some reason Bitnami WAMP Stack keeps on FAILING to install in a deeper directory `D:\***\***\***\***\***\wampstack`. It ONLY works when I'm installing in the root (one folder in `D:\Bitnami\wampstack`). My set up NEEDS to have the stack server installed deeper down for organization's sake, but it won't work. It keeps failing.
I then tried installing it in the root directory, then tried moving the whole folder (since IT IS supposed to be self-contained.) into the proper directory (deeper down), and then changing the ImagePath of the wampserverApache and wampserverMySQL to reflect that of the new location. IT STILL WON'T START.
I keep getting this error:

```
> Starting all servers... Starting MySQL Database... Exit code: 1
> Stdout:
> 
> Stderr: Unknown error starting mysql Starting Apache Web Server...
> Exit code: 1 Stdout:
> 
> Stderr: Unknown error starting apache
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Or am I just doing something extremely wrong. Please help. My OCD is killing me spent a good 3 hours on this stupid issue. I just don't understand why the installer won't let me just install in a deeper directory. It lets me change the directory during installation but it doesn't ever work. Bitnami really should fix this if they're letting you change the directory in which to install, or at least limit the choices so that the user doesn't get stuck needlessly trying to figure out the problem with the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami developer here.

The problem you're facing must be related to the length of your path. This is a NTFS limitation, this is a related case:

[Maximum filename length in NTFS (Windows XP and Windows Vista)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista)

Could you check if your path is longer than 255 characters?

Also spaces in directory names can be an issue, as all this software is ported from unix where spaces in directory names require the use of quotes around paths that contain spaces. So either check the config and put quotes around your paths that contain spaces like `"folder 1/folder 2"` or remove/replace the spaces in the paths.

Comment: I keep thinking that, but I'm well below the 255 character limit... this is the path: `D:\23 letters + 3 spaces\14 letters + 1 space\6 letters\wampstack-7.0.18-0\all installation files go here` @david

Comment: Oh wait are you saying the length of the ImagePath as found in the Registry Editor?

Comment: Spaces in directory names can cause issues/problems with most WAMP stack tools.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - wow I wished I knew that. IT IS FINALLY FIXED. I changed all the spaces to underscores. That trivial thing really needs to find a fix, especially since Bitnami allows for a custom directory location. At least make some type of IF statement during the installation that checks if the directory has spaces in it, so you don't waste developers' time... Jesus Christ. Issue is finally resolved. Thanks for the tips. 4 hours...