# Why CreateDirectoryEx with long folder name is not working?

Tags: winapi, max-path

This is a sample code i have written to check if i am able to create a folder with name length greater than `MAX_PATH` -

```
wstring s = L"D:\\Test";
wstring s2 = L"\\?\D:\\datafffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffr700000000000000datafffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffr700000000000000datafffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffr700000000000000datafffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffr700000000000000datafffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffr700000000000000";

int ret = CreateDirectoryEx(s.c_str(), s2.c_str(), NULL);

int error = GetLastError();
```

It did not work, the returned error is **ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND**. Can anyone please tell me whats the problem in the code?

**Note:** "D:\Test" folder is an existing folder. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: look for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265782/6401656) - *Individual components of a filename (i.e. each subdirectory along the path, and the final filename) are limited to 255 characters*

Comment: @RbMm Please check the edit.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in an edit. This one is done. You should upvote answers by xMRi and RbRm and accept that of xMRi. Don't edit the question to change the subject matter that has already been addressed.

Comment: As for the contents of your edit, almost certainly the parent directory in your destination did not exist. Which is what the error told you. You need to look at the error codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

need not confuse **Maximum file name length (path component)** and **Maximum path length** - see [Limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681827%28VS.85%29.aspx#limits)

the **Maximum file name length** is <= 255 Unicode characters for all file systems

and **Maximum path length**
32,760 Unicode characters **with each path component no more than 255 characters**

---

initial error was by using `L"\\?\"` prefix - really it must be `L"\\\\?\\"` because c/c++ translate `"\\"` to `\` - but this already only language specific error.

if fix it - must be error `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` (converted from NTSTATUS `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID` ) because path component which you use more than 255 characters

Comment: That would not result in `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` surely. So once the escaping is fixed, that's the next problem I guess.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - yes, I miss at begin that \\?\ used instead \\\\?\\. error must be `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` (or NTSTATUS `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID`) if fix tis typo -anyway name exceeds 255 characters

Comment: If you look at the edit history, and comments to the other answer, then this is exactly what happens. First of all he tried with incorrect escaping, and got `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`. Then he fixed that and saw `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`. Then he fixed that with multiple directories all with length less than 255 and got back to `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` because the directories did not exist.

Comment: I just thought this answer was more helpful to me. The first error was trivial and i fixed that after posting this question. After this answer i realize the actual problem in the code and my approach to create long directory.

Comment: `CreateDirectory/Ex()` does not create missing intermediate folders. If you try to create `D:\x\y\z` and `x` or `y` do not exist, the function fails. The documentation says so: "*`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` One or more intermediate directories do not exist. **This function only creates the final directory in the path**.*" So, you would have to create `D:\x` first, then create `D:\x\y`, then create `D:\x\y\z`, ignoring any `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` errors along the way. Or, do what the documentation says: "*To create all intermediate directories on the path, use the `SHCreateDirectoryEx` function*".

Answer (score 3):

Because the syntax is simply wrong. You have to escape the backslash. So the prefix should be `L"\\\\?\\"`.

```
wstring s2 = L"\\\\?\\D:\\dataff...";
```

Comment: I did that actually. I was getting `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` error if i was using "\\\\?\\".

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov Trial and error is no way to program is it. You know that \ is an escape character in a string. Are you hoping that the compiler will forget this fact? You know that `L"\\\\?\\"` is correct, so if you have a problem, it must be elsewhere. And in this case that elsewhere is explained by RbRm's answer. This answer is the correct one. It answers the question you asked. It explains why you encounter `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`. The `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` is a subsequent issue.

Comment: Alternatively use C++11 raw string literal so you don't need to escape: `LR"(\\?\D:\dataff.....)"`

Answer (score -1):

Because the path sizes are limited (to 160 caracters I think on W7 but not sure)

Comment: If you are talking about `MAX_PATH` then its 260. But i think using `\\?\` prefix should let one beat the `MAX_PATH` restriction.

Comment: @user6106573 I think it is in fact you who needs to read the content of that linked article with greater attention to detail