# ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory throwing on long filename

Tags: c#, .net, io, zip

I am extracting a zip file like this

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFile, extractTo);
```

But I am getting a

```
{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\....many subfolders\\Extremely long filename'."}
```

The zip file contains a file with a very long path and filename c.a. 280 chars in total. I am not sure if that is the problem I enabled long path as demonstrated here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/

If I open the path in explorer it opens but the file with the long filename is not there. If I open the zip file the file is there so there seems to be a problem extracting file with long filename.

Is it possible to skip a file during the zip extraction or allowing extracting files with long filenames?

Comment: ZipFile.OpenRead

Comment: Note that skipping files is quite a dangerous thing to do, especially if you don't tell the user you've done that.

Comment: Hi @DavidG yes I totally agree. It would be best if all the files could be extracted. Any clue why the file is not being extracted why the error is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.FullName.Length > 280)
            continue;

        entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine("your path", entry.FullName));
    }
}
```

`ZipFile.OpenRead` will allow you to inspect the content of the zip file. Then you can enumerate thru the `.Entries` property to find out all the files inside the archive and decide if you want to proceed with extract based on the file name length .

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I think the code is self explanatory enough. Skip a file if the name is too long and proceed extract if its not as described in the question

Comment: Thanks @Steve for the solution. Of course it would be best if all the files could be extracted. Any clue why the file with a long name is not being extracted? Is there a limitation in the ZipFile archive?

Comment: @doorman there is a limitation on Windows (260 chars) and you can't bypass that.

Comment: Even though I allow it? Maybe I need to restart? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/

Comment: Why is this marked as a solution? I am getting the same issue and I can't just skip extracting a file nor do I have control over how the zipped directories are named. There should be an actual solution and not "just skip it".

Comment: @Dobob Windows has a restriction on path length. So you either skip it or rename it. There really isn't a 3rd way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Windows based file system, the maximum length of a filename is 255 characters. Note: the folder path is included in the file name when calculating the file name length. If you have a long folder path, then you might want to try extracting to c:\temp, which is only using 7 characters. Thus leaving you with 248 characters to work with. If you have file names longer than that within your archive, you might want to address that issue first that way your not having to exclude files from extract.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee681827(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm

[Maximum filename length in NTFS (Windows XP and Windows Vista)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista)