# Is there such a thing as a filename that is too long?

Tags: software-quality

I'm thinking about filenames which are very long and therefore considered as bad practice. For example, the [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)
 project on GitHub contains a Java file that is called "CompletableMergeDelayErrorIterable.java". I'm wondering if filenames like these should be shortened in order to enhance the readability. Is there a rule of thumb? Or should a filename just be self-explanatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For NTFS file systems (i.e. Windows), an individual filename is limited to 255 characters. The same goes for any parts of a path, like directory names. Full paths should be shorter than the constant `MAX_PATH`, which is 260 characters.

See [Maximum filename length in NTFS (Windows XP and Windows Vista)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista)

For Linux, the maximum length is 255 bytes in most cases (depends on the exact file system used).

See [Filename length limits on linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux)

So yes, long file (and path) names can cause problems and should be avoided!

Additionally, very long class names make your code harder to read. If you want to convey that a class supports certain features, it should be sufficient to mark it with the appropriate interface(s) (e.g. `Iterable<T>`).

Comment: But isn't it already a problem to have more than 25 or 30 characters in a name? It really affects the readability in my opinion.